# SQL INNER JOIN - Select Data from Another Table based on value on another row

Tags: sql, inner-join

Difficult to explain my problem, but I'll try my best...

I am trying to build a view from various tables, but I want two extra columns "HomeTeamID" and "AwayTeamID" that brings in the appropriate IDs, even for other markets for that particular event.

I've attached the data to show you what I'm trying to achieve (spreadsheet [here](http://www.filedropper.com/betfairhomeawayrunners))

[Image data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF0nk.png)

Comment: please add tables in a cutAndPastable manner, tables definitions etc.

Comment: I have seen it. couldn't cut and paste from it so lost interest. sorry.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, maybe try help?

Comment: I did try, that's why I'm here :)

Comment: I think the answer I posted is what he need

Comment: I've added a link for the spreadsheet above, I think @Borna is on the right track

Comment: @Some One I don't see table Team, do you have it?

Comment: Team is just simply a table with two columns, TeamID and Name

Answer (score -1):

You have to join 2 times,

```
SELECT HomeTeam.ID, AwayTeam.ID from xyz INNER JOIN Team as HomeTeam on Team.ID = HomeTeam.ID INNER JOIN Team as AwayTeam on Team.ID = AwayTeam.ID
```

Answer (score -1):

Think I've got it, but got another problem. Takes 23 seconds if I DON'T include the HomeTeamID in the SELECT area. When I DO INCLUDE the HomeTeamID, I get the following error:

'Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140737648001024' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.
'

Visual Studio is running inside Windows 8.1 within Parallels, due to restrictions I've only got 1GB spare disk space. The tables themselves have around 50,000 records in total (the MDF / LDF files are only 40MB, so I'm struggling to see what the problem is :/

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    BetfairEvents.OpenDate AS EventDateTime,
    MarketT.Name AS MarketType, HomeContractT.RunnderID AS HomeTeamID,
    CompetitionsT.Name AS CompetitionName, ContractsT.ID AS ContractID, ContractsT.RunnerID AS SelectionID,
    ContractsT.LayOdds AS Price, ContractsT.LayAvailable AS Available,
    RunnerT.Name AS RunnerName
    FROM BetfairEvents
    INNER JOIN BetfairMarket MarketT ON MarketT.EventID = BetfairEvents.ID
    INNER JOIN BetfairCompetitions CompetitionsT ON CompetitionsT.ID = MarketT.CompetitionID
    INNER JOIN BetfairContract ContractsT ON ContractsT.MarketID = MarketT.ID
    INNER JOIN BetfairRunner RunnerT ON RunnerT.ID = ContractsT.RunnerID
    INNER JOIN BetfairMarketType MarketTypeT ON MarketTypeT.Name = MarketT.Name
    INNER JOIN BetfairMarket HomeMarketT ON MarketT.EventID = BetfairEvents.ID
    INNER JOIN BetfairContract HomeContractT ON HomeContractT.SelectionID = 1
```

Comment: Apologies, I missed that from the sheet, Team is just a two column table: ID and Name

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with your query, it takes times because your are using multiple joins, which can get rly slow... thats how it is with fully normalized datababases... slow read...